# WPF Drag&Drop databinding only works for Dataset not EF?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, entity-framework

I want to be able to use the drag & drop databinding feature in Visual Studio 2012. So following [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg610409) Microsoft tutorial, I added the `AdventureWorks2012` mdf file to the project.

Now if I use the `DataSet` option in the wizard, the three database tables I want are added to the `datasources` window and I can do a drag & drop to create fields on my window automatically and have the binding setup.

**However, that is done with SQL Adaptors. I want to use pure EntityFramework Binding instead.**

[image: Added AdventureWOrks2012 version as **Add Existing File**]

[image]

[image]

**Problem:**

But I want to do it the EntityFramework way. If I go one step back and choose EntityData Model in the wizard, the datasource is never added. And I can't drag and drop fields from the datasource window to my `MainWindow.Xaml`

[image]
[image]

How can I avoid using XSD file and do it the EFway. SQL way works but it is too verbose.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a dataset, and have set up a datasource, when using **EF**, you must manually create a **DataSource**.

[image: Image showing how to add a data source]

Here's a link to the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/w4dd7z6t.aspx)